# Can I use suncalc to create a data table with sunrise and sunset times for each date with individual geographic locations?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I'm trying to write a `function` to output sunrise and sunset times on each day of a year for individual counties in a state. Currently, I have a `table` with columns for counties and their `latitudes` and `longitudes`, eg:

| County | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Grand Junction | 65 | -80 |
| Larimer | 62 | -75 |

I also have generated a `table` with `dates` for the year I'm interested in:

```
start.date = "20200101"; end.date = "20201231"
Dates <- seq(ymd(start.date), ymd(end.date), by = "days")
```

And I have the `suncalc`-package that I can use for calculating the sunrise and sunset times for individual dates, eg:

```
library(suncalc)

getSunlightTimes(date = 20200101, lat = 65, lon = -80, tz = "MST")
```

Knowing this, what would be the best way to generate a `data.frame` with sunrise and sunset times for each county on each day of the year?

Part of this is just me being confused on how to pull from my `table` properly to avoid inputting code a few hundred times, and the other part is being concerned about making it look clean and being easy to navigate (but with so many values, I know that might be inevitable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
my_df <- data.frame(
  County = c("Grand Junction", "Larimer"),
  Latitude = c(65,62),
  Longitude = c(-80,-75)
)

# install.packages("suncalc")
library(suncalc)
# install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)
start.date = "20200101"; end.date = "20201231"
Dates <- seq(ymd(start.date),ymd(end.date), by = "days")
# install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
sun_df <- expand.grid(Dates = Dates,County = my_df$County) %>% 
  left_join(my_df) %>%
  group_by(Dates, County, Latitude, Longitude) %>% 
  mutate(sunrise = getSunlightTimes(Dates,Latitude,Longitude,tz = "MST")$sunrise,
         sunset = getSunlightTimes(Dates,Latitude,Longitude,tz = "MST")$sunset)
```

This will give the information you want in one table without having to code specifically for each county:

```
> head(sun_df)
# A tibble: 6 × 6
# Groups:   Dates, County, Latitude, Longitude [6]
  Dates      County         Latitude Longitude sunrise            
  <date>     <chr>             <dbl>     <dbl> <dttm>             
1 2020-01-01 Grand Junction       65       -80 2020-01-01 08:28:20
2 2020-01-02 Grand Junction       65       -80 2020-01-02 08:27:05
3 2020-01-03 Grand Junction       65       -80 2020-01-03 08:25:41
4 2020-01-04 Grand Junction       65       -80 2020-01-04 08:24:10
5 2020-01-05 Grand Junction       65       -80 2020-01-05 08:22:32
6 2020-01-06 Grand Junction       65       -80 2020-01-06 08:20:46
# … with 1 more variable: sunset <dttm>
```